# image src doesnt change after upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, try-catch

i am making an upload with Ajaxupload plugin and i am using this function in OnComplete event of ajaxupload;

```
function degis(){
var a = "<?php echo $id; ?>";
document.getElementById("imga").src = "../artwork/"+a+"/logo.jpg?dummy=371662";
document.getElementById("imga").style.width = "500px";
document.getElementById("imga").style.height = "175px";
}
```

but new uploaded image doesnt appear for a reason. i tried that "?dummy=371662" but didnt work.

i am also using this for Onsubmit event of ajaxupload

```
function updeg(){
var a = "uploading.gif";
document.getElementById("imga").style.width = "50px";
document.getElementById("imga").style.height = "50px";
document.getElementById("imga").src = a;

}
</script>
```

this is the html of this element

```
 <img id="imga" alt="" height="175px" src="../artwork/<?php echo $id; ?>/logo.jpg?dummy=371662" width="500px">
```

Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: Please show the associated HTML.

Comment: Your HTML shows the same thing as the JS.  Are you saying that it works in HTML but not in JS?  Is the $id the only thing that changes between the two?

Comment: when page loads "imga" element src is ok, but after upload completed and it calls that degis() function to change "imga" src attr. to new uploaded image, it shows old one, i hope i can explain right sorry

Comment: by the way $id is always same, new uploaded image names is also that $id variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edits and comments above, I think you need something like this:

```
function junk() {
    return (new Date()).getTime() + Math.round(Math.random());
}

function degis() {
    var img = document.getElementById("imga");
    if (img) {
        img.src = "../artwork/<?php echo $id; ?>/logo.jpg?nocache=" + junk();
        img.style.width = "500px";
        img.style.height = "175px";
    }
}
```

Your previous attempt to bypass the cache doesn't work because your "dummy" value is the same each time.  By use of a `junk()` function, as above, you get a different random value each time, ensuring that the image cannot be cached.

Comment: ok but without that modification how can i change image after upload process?

Comment: oh sorry you are talking about height and width, i am changing it because there is one more function for OnSubmit event of ajaxupload which is change height and width, i am editing my question

Comment: Edited to answer the current question and comments.