# How to force browser to refresh just one image after .attr('src', url) change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax upload script that returns an image that should swap out an exiting loaded image in the dom.

For example

```
<img src="http://site.com/user1-profile-pic.jpg" id="profile" />
```

and uploading a new image returns json

```
{"url": "http://site.com/user1-profile-pic.jpg" }
```

I then run jQuery

```
$("#profile").attr('src', myjson.url);
```

but the image url is always the same, so I want to bust the cache for that image to load it again. Could it be as simple as appending `?timestamp` onto the end of the image URL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [image src doesnt change after upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626964/image-src-doesnt-change-after-upload)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's the same because it's cached as you are using the same name, the trick is to use a different name.

As you can't use a different name, we append something to it:

```
var dt = new Date(); 
$("#profile").attr( 'src', myjson.url + '?dt=' + dt.getTime() );
```

in just one call (as [Sushil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960713/sushil) says):

```
$("#profile").attr( 'src', myjson.url + '?dt=' + (+new Date()) );
```

this will output as:

[image]

Comment: `$("#profile").attr( 'src', myjson.url + '?dt=' +new Date() );`

to avoid an extra step of .getTime

Comment: @Sushil you mean ```'?dt=' + new Date().getTime()``` ?

Comment: @ed209 can be anything, as long it is random/unique. With `'?dt=' +new Date()` **you will have** a link of `'?dt=Wed%20Sep%2012%202012%2013:10:20%20GMT+0200%20(Romance%20Daylight%20Time)` witch is also unique :)

Comment: nope i mean `+new Date()` it returns the time milliseconds directly

my comment shud have been like this `$("#profile").attr( 'src', myjson.url + '?dt=' + (+new Date()) );`

Comment: @Sushil no it does not, `new Date()` string  output is the entire Date  as `Wed Sep 12 2012 13:12:21 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)`.

Comment: yes `new Date()` will return entire Date but `+new Date()` will return the milliseconds

Comment: coz u are doing it wrong...`$("#profile").attr( 'src', myjson.url + '?dt=' + (+new Date()) );` there are 2 `+` signs after ur `dt?=` did u notice that?